# cognitoUser.getUserAttributes gives an empty error object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

My code:

```
cognitoUser.getUserAttributes(function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            window.Raven.captureMessage("Error [getUserAttributes]: " + JSON.stringify(err));
            cognitoUser.signOut();
            return;
        }

        var attributes = {};

        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            if (res[i].getName() !== "sub") {
                attributes[res[i].getName()] = res[i].getValue();
            }
        }

        store.dispatch({type: 'user/attributes', attributes: attributes});
    });
```

Somehow the callback has an error, but it is empty. What does that mean?
ie. `err = {}`

Also `res = null`

Comment: I tried a few things to reproduce this but was unable to.  `err` is null or non-empty no matter what I do.  Perhaps you could log out the `cognitoUser` object right before this call and post it?

Comment: Right before this call I login the cognitoUser

Comment: I realize my comment was worded poorly.  By "log out" I mean `console.log(cognitoUser)` so we could examine the contents of the object.  Not log out the user (which would be silly).  Specifically, I'm wondering what the `cognitoUser.signInUserSession` object looks like.  Does it contain an accessToken, idToken, and refreshToken?

Comment: Ok I will do that, thanks